# File system issue when porting an ASP.NET application to Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, migration, log4net, azure-storage

I have an existing ASP.NET website that I would like to port to Azure within my free trial.

I would like the migration to be as painless as possible. The application uses log4net and NHibernate, plus it needs to share data with an application supposed to run on a virtual server.

Two questions can be asked as 1

#### How do I configure paths in Web.config to access a shared drive?

I need to configure the paths into which logs will be stored **and**, most important, I have to specify where the application will read the files written by the daemon that will run on my Azure Linux VM.

When both the app and the daemon ran on the same server (yes, I had Mono running fine) I just had to choose a shared local directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm totally understanding the scenario, but I'll try to give you a few options.

One - Windows Azure Web Sites (currently in Preview) could be a great option for your ASP.NET site.  Of course, it depends what needs your site has.  But, you can write your log4net files with web site and using NHibernate too.

Two - Web roles work great for situations like this.  You would likely have to change some code to use blob storage for persistant file storage.  You could use Windows Azure drives as a way to get a persistent location for log files.  Windows Azure drives don't have a pre-determined drive letter, so you'd want to use the API to get to that.  That may, or may not, be a good option for your situation.  With web roles you could also write the log4net files to local storage and use Windows Azure diagnostics to transfer them periodically to blob storage.  Just another way to persist the files.

Three - Using Windows Azure Virtual Machines (currently in Preview) you could write the log files to a data disk, which is backed by blob storage.

In the end, if you have files you need to share across instances and/or roles, then leveraging blob storage is likely your best option.